# When should we use Infile statement

Tags: file-io, sas

I need a little help from SAS experts. I am trying to import excel files into SAS environment using Infile statement. But I an facing errors. Could you please help to enlighten me in which situation Infile statement work properly?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Following the answer given, if you need any further clarification, please supply the SAS code you are using, the version of SAS and the extension of the Excel file you are trying to read, i.e., the last letters after the period ('.'), e.g., 'xls', 'xlsx', etc.

Answer (score 0):

An infile statement in a data step is typically used for reading text files, e.g. csv or fixed-width data. You can in theory read any file you like with one, but for things like excel files that have a complex internal structure, you should the tools that already exist in SAS for that purpose.

In your situation you should use a libname statement. This might be useful to you:
https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug-cn/2014/PT/PharmaSUG-China-2014-PT09.pdf

Answer (score 0):

INFILE statements are for reading data from text files. XLSX files are zipped XML files.

There are two primary ways to read/import an XLSX file. One is to use PROC IMPORT and import the file directly into SAS. The second is to use the LIBNAME statement and that allows you to treat it more like a SAS data set from the start.